# How to deal with a contracting client trying to get me to go fulltime

Tags: professionalism, salary, contractors, fulltime

I work for a contracting firm contracting for a major company. I've been working at this company for almost 6 months now and everyone is very satisfied with my performance. One of my superiors, a manager, is trying really hard to get me to go full-time. This is not the first time this has happened, so I explained that although I enjoyed working for the company, but that at the moment I needed the money I received from contracting over less pay and the package I would get, but that I was truly flattered and would be happy to consider it in the future.

My manager then told me that their pay was actually very competitive and gave me a range of where i'm likely to start at if I went full-time. That range was around what I'm being payed as a contractor. I thanked her for the information and that she could send me more information, but that I would need time to consider before making a decision.

The issue is that the person who hired me at the contracting firm is a person I consider a mentor, and if I had to pick, I'd rather keep working for him.  He and I discussed this the last time I was offered a full-time position and he assured me that the company would not be able to match what he pays me. I signed a non-compete agreement when he hired me, but I know he would be willing to let me out of it on the condition that I give him time to hire someone to replace me.

What is the best course of action here? Should I discuss this with my boss or keep it to myself?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere And how do you suggest I turn down the manager in a way where I can bring up the conversation of going fulltime when I feel comfortable and not be asked about it ever 2 months?

Comment: Only you can decide what is best for you. We can't weigh the relative merits of staying with your mentor versus going to a permanent position.

Comment: @DJClayworth I understand that, i'm just asking if it would be a good idea to bring it up with him or if I should keep it to myself. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Get a raise? Get a full time position? Decline a full time position politely?

Comment: A "mentor" that pushes a non-complete on you is not necessarily a mentor you want.

Comment: Something to consider: There's always a risk that if you don't accept the offer to go full-time, she could just end the contract. She's paying a significant premium to have you as a contractor and that's how she can offer something similar to what you're currently making. If she has to lower her costs, you could find yourself on the short end of that decision in which case you've gained nothing.

Comment: Your mentor may be less helpful than you suspect when the time comes.  If you leave you are essentially stealing his client after all.

Comment: As @DJClayworth said, you're asking for us to make up your mind for you, which is off-topic (VTC). If that's not what you wanted to ask you should [edit] your question.

Comment: Are "boss" and "manager" the same person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you:

1. I would get something from the hiring manager in writing, like an employment offer, before starting to think about it.
2. If the money they pay is comparable to what you are getting from your contracting firm, and additional benefits are putting the full time employment on top, I would go talk to your so-called mentor with all the data in my hand.
3. I would ask your contracting firm to make you a counter offer, as you hold this person, your mentor, in such high regards.
4. Also I'd consider that if I am making, say $50/hr contracting, your company is making north of $25/hr on your billing. So, if they start to give me the BS that, they are sending you with razor thin margins to this client, I'd understand that their priority is making money not keeping you on board.
5. If they come up with a counter offer, say $60/hr, on the above example, cutting their margin to $15/hr, you will know that you are being appreciated and it is in your best interest to stay with a company who values you, rather than jumping ship to the highest bidder.
6. If they say, $50 is our final offer, then you need to make the hard talk with your mentor, convince him to let you out of your non-compete, on the basis of doing whatever is best for yourself before whatever is the best for the company.

All in all, do not burn bridges prematurely but don't be a sucker either.

Answer (score 4):

I get this all the time, I just politely refuse, I don't bother with explanations.

The motivations behind trying to get a contractor to go full time are usually money ones. Quite probably the manager likes your work, but wants it cheaper since it comes out of his dept's budget.

Mention it to your boss if you want, but this is normal enough. If the job isn't something you're actually considering then it's best to ignore it and leave out the drama.

When staff start hard lining for more pay using a client as leverage, I wish them luck and let them go. The thing is that you lose the staff member, but you'll lose that clients work anyway, because they will no longer need your services and they just headhunted your staff which is not something an employer forgets.

Every time I've done this I've had the client eventually come back and charged them a lot more. But once I've let a person go, that's it. They're relatively easy to replace. As an employer I'm looking for loyalty, I won't rehire someone who took a client.

If you don't want to burn bridges and upset your boss, then go find your own job, don't steal his.

Comment: I agree that hiring manager might not have OP's best interests in mind.

Comment: Neither is the contracting company owner/manager. Money talks. And I'd rather have it talk to me, all other things being equal.

Comment: @MelBurslan I'd rather not get into murky ethical ground and/or burn bridges with someone who I viewed as a mentor. Money is important, but I'm in a career for the long term, other considerations can over ride the money part. It's summed up in my last sentence. I don't mind an employee getting a new job and moving forwards... but if he steals my client, that's different, that hits my bottom line.